# XSD Error: Name cannot begin with the "<" character

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an **XSD** which I am trying to load into Liquid XML editor but get error saying it it not valid with the error message from the title of this post. My xsd is in the following format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:element name="frequency" default="config"<xs:annotation><xs:documentation xml:lang="en"> TBD
            </xs:documentation></xs:annotation><xs:simpleType> <xs:restriction base=xs:"integer"><xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
<xs:maxInclusive value="10"/>
</xs:restriction> </xs:simpleType> </xs:element>
```

Im not really sure why the error in the title is occurring. I checked for white spaces and matching brackets and that all seems to be ok.

The error is reffering the the bolded"<": default="config"

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: THis is not a correct XML document. The element is not closed after the `default` attribute.

Comment: Thank you! I am getting a second error saying that "xs is an undeclared prefix." Do you know why that may be? I thought xs: or xsd: both work here

Comment: I realized my error: I did not ad the namespace declaration: <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
...
</xs:schema>

Comment: I would strongly recommend using an editor that understands XML, and preferably one that understands XSD. It will save you an awful lot of time (and it would have saved the 14 viewers of this post time too....)